# Text is causing CSS placement issues

Tags: php, css

I have a comics website and would like to place text (database field "description") under each comic thumbnail.

I have 2 questions:

**Question 1)** I'm not sure why, but when I place text under a comic, it forces the comic row below it to offset by one.

[image]

But otherwise, without text... it lines up fine:

[image]

The CSS is as follows:

```
    .comics {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 5px 30px 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: url(images/SiteDesign/comicbg.png) no-repeat 0 0;

    /*Need to set width on this >= to thumber width so description text will wrap*/
    width: 220px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
```

PHP:

```
    echo '<li>';
    echo    '<span class="comics"><a href=".?action=viewimage&site='.$site. '&id=' . $row['id'] .'">
            <img src="./scripts/thumber.php?img=.' . $thumbpath.$row['thumb'] . '&mw=220&mh=220"/></a>' . 
            '<br /><br /> ' . $row['description'] . '</span>';                              
echo '</li>';
```

I feel like I'm doing the CSS correctly, so not sure why it's offsetting.

**Question 2)**

The only reason I'm adding text at the bottom is because Go Daddy says I do not have enough occurences of key words, such as "comics", or "artwork" on my pages for SEO. If I add this text, often including keywords, would that improve my SEO?

Thanks!

EDIT -----

If I do `display: inline-block;` and `verticle-align: text-top;` for li, do I need text for each post? otherwise it seems to awkwardly push up one of the images.

[image]

Comment: The text probably overlaps into the row below which means the `float:left` moves itself across. You can use the Chrome Inspector to identify this by highlighting HTML elements. Adding additional information about the comics is also likely to help your SEO as there is more relevant keywords present.

Comment: @diggerworld put that in an answer! ;) also if anyone needs to visualize it: http://jsbin.com/jksanasf/2/

Comment: Maybe it's silly, but have you tried setting the height of the elements you float? Also the max-height? That should keep them in order, shouldn't it?

Comment: @hakre that seems to work. So I guess I should just do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't guarantee that each element will have the same height, you want `display: inline-block`, not float.  Also, it should be on the `li`.

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

You can stuff whatever you want within the `li` and each row will line up across the top.  Demo (using divs): http://jsfiddle.net/ffr3M/

Comment: Thanks cimmanon, but if I do `display: inline-block;` and `verticle-align: text-top;`, do I need text for each post? otherwise it seems to awkwardly push up one of the images. See above edit.

Comment: Nope.  You just need different styling on the images:  http://jsfiddle.net/ffr3M/3/.  Giving them `display: block` should be just enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can try having distinctly separate rows that won't affect how the rows below float. You can accomplish this by adding the following after each row's set of comic thumbnails:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

see this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gLMw9/

Comment: @Growler if you do this make sure to add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after the text rows as well. Then it won't matter how tall the text rows are, you're images should line up properly

Answer (score 1):

If you add the same amount of text below every comic I bet it will all flow correctly. You could try inserting a div with a fixed height around every description, e.g.:

```
<div style="height:50px;">' . $row['description'] . '</div>
```

although you may wish to change your other wrapping spans to divs as well...

Comment: Why add the constraint to have "same amount of text below every comic"? What if image and text are higher than 50px or zoomed or displayed on some OS with different fonts than expected? `height` property will crop content :(

Comment: I was assuming his descriptions would always be relatively short and uniform but yes, you could run into the issues you describe.